# What is this brace bit cutter tool exactly and how is it used?

Tags: hand-tools, tools, traditional-techniques, tool-identification

I was liberating some old hand tools from my grandfather's shop again, before grandma throws them in the garbage, and found some more interesting things. This time I am sure that this one is a woodworking tool!

[image]

It looks like a tool that's a tapering tool that could be used to make tenons on chair legs or something similar. It seems clear that it is meant to be used in a brace. Seems hard to try and cut a tenon though as I would think the tool would easily drift.

Following is the only markings on the tool as well as a view from the bottom that shows the blade.

[image]

What do you think this is called and more importantly what is it used for?

Comment: I don't recognize the tool, but I applaud rescuing ... You might tell your grandma that there are people interested in buying tools generally and sometimex old tools in particular even if some restoration is needed. A good hand-tool should stay in use until it is completely worn out, which can be genetations.

Comment: Thought: Tenion cutter?

Comment: I can't comment on the tool either, but Exchange 5.5?

Comment: (If it was me, I'd rescue the whole workshop first and sort it out later.)

Comment: @PeterK I needed to find a book I would never open to use as a monitor stand.

Comment: @Matt: These are immensely useful woodworking tools, too -- I use my hardcover Exchange 2000 programming book with a 44lb kettlebell on the top for pressing down small veneer laminates (no kidding :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hollow auger**

[U.S. Patent 203,384](http://pdfpiw.uspto.gov/.piw?PageNum=0&docid=00203384&IDKey=172148E7B57E%0D%0A&HomeUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fpatft.uspto.gov%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fpatimg.htm) is for a "Hollow auger" or more specifically for improvements to a hollow auger.  "What's a hollow auger?" you ask.  Well, as @Keshlam suggested it is a device for cutting tenons on chair rungs or spokes as demonstrated by a similar device on a [You Tube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVxo4qxq8jc) video.  It's a device that, rather than drilling a hole, it drills what fits into a hole.

The patent claims that the improvement is that this version of the hollow auger is adjustable so as to "obviate the necessity of using a separate auger for each sized tenon."

I will leave it to @Matt to figure out exactly how this one works, but it will require a brace for turning the cutting mechanism and a vice for holding the workpiece.

With tongue in cheek, I suggest that this device might also be an answer to my question from several months back: [How can I make my own dowels?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1077/how-can-i-make-my-own-dowels)

Comment: Good research pointer!

Comment: I found his out as well when I Google'd the patent number on the base. Was going to answer today if no one else did. Good work

Comment: This tool would not be good for making dowels though. Tenon yes but it can only cut in a few inches

Comment: @Matt Short dowels it is!

Answer (score 3):

This tool is a tapering tool for chair, or table legs.

How to use:

With the leg in a vise, square end to one side, the tapering tool is brought slowly and carefully (adjusting from the square end) down to the foot end one layer at a time. It is adjusted using an adjustable hand wrench.

I am old-school (75 years old) and I used this tool when I was a youth of 12 years.