# Best way to hide counter sunk screws

Tags: technique, screws

How can I best hide these screw heads? Wood filler probably will crack...

[image]

Comment: [Very related](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/210/making-fake-pseudo-plugs-or-caps/211#211)

Comment: Short answer is it's best not to try. Instead you're hiding counterbored screws. So, [very related](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3612/what-joining-methods-would-be-best-for-the-legs-and-other-areas-of-a-height-adju/3613#3613). Note however doing this after the fact can mean your current screws end up being too long and may need to be shortened, or shorter screws (of the same gauge) swapped in.

Comment: Is this joint glued also? If it's held together only by the screws it's considered good practice to leave the screw heads visible for any subsequent re-tightening that may be needed.

Comment: @Graphus: Yes... I... did also glue it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider to remove the screws and perform a counterbore or use a forstner bit to the depth of the screw head. Select the diameter to match your selected wood plug diameter. Return the screw, glue in the plug, sand the plug flush.

[image: counterbore bits]

You can purchase a wood plug cutter, sort of a hole saw without a center drill, and cut your plugs from the same wood, for a better appearance match.

[image: wood plug cutters]

Answer (score 1):

Places like Lee Valley, et al, sell hardwood "buttons" or "plugs". For shallow holes there are even stick-on veneers, but it looks like you need a proper hardwood plug, either store-bought or home-made.